# In the Chamber of Secrets film, were there any signs pointing to the identity of the culprit?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the *Chamber of Secrets* book, there are a few signs that the flesh and bone culprit has been acting abnormally throughout the year. I don't think that there were enough for many readers to identify the culprit ahead of time, but they were undeniably present. In the film, I'm not so sure. Were there any scenes, background details, or any other sort of hints that pointed to the identity of the culprit in the film adaptation, prior to the scene where we're told their identity?

Comment: The culprit being Ginney Weasley? Or Tom Riddle diary version?

Comment: @fez Definitely Ginny. Even in the book, I can't think of any hints that point to Tom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pay close attention to the bookstore scene, you can tell that the number of books that Malfoy takes out of Ginny's cauldron is less than the number that he returns.

Comment: @J.Mini The amount he takes out is less than he returns. The amount he returns is more than the amount he takes out.

Comment: I have to admit, I was hoping that there would be a lot more than this. Apparently, there isn't! Well done!